# MongoDB rest API for DB access events not working : 401 Client Error: Unauthorized

Tags: mongodb

I have been trying to fetch DB access history using "dbAccessHistory" api but getting the following error :

> 03-23-2020 06:34:34.201 +0000 ERROR ExecProcessor - message from
>   "python xxxxx/rest_ta/bin/rest.py" HTTP Request error: 401 Client
>   Error: Unauthorized

API documentation : https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/api/access-tracking-get-database-history-clustername/

Please let me know why is the permission error happening.

Comment: Please refer to https://httpstatuses.com/401. You must be missing the header   "WWW-Authenticate"   or providing a bad value.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be including the [programmatic keys](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/configure-api-access/#programmatic-api-keys) in your request. I've written a small [Python package](https://pypi.org/project/mongodbatlas/) for test access to a cluster. Install that and try the command:

```
atlascli --privatekey <your private key>--publickey <your public key> --list
```

This will list your cluster resources if you have connectivity. Make sure to configure the 
[API white-list](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/configure-api-access/#limit-api-operations-to-whitelisted-ipv4-addresses). This is different from the white-list for driver connections.